# Check if element is outside window React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, intersection-observer

I am trying to create a code that checks whether the div element is outside the window, or not. The issue with the code is that it ignores the result on the `isOpen` state update, so as ignores if the element is slightly outside the window screen. Is there a chance it can be further adjusted?

```
export const useOnScreen = (ref, rootMargin = '0px') => {
    const [isIntersecting, setIntersecting] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
            ([entry]) => {
                setIntersecting(entry.isIntersecting);
            },
            {
                rootMargin
            }
        );

        if (ref.current) {
            observer.observe(ref.current);
        }

        return () => {
            observer.unobserve(ref.current);
        };
    }, []);

    return isIntersecting;
};

export default useOnScreen;
```

Usage:

```
const packRef = useRef(null);

const isVisible = useOnScreen(packRef);

{ !optionsOpen && (
  <div className="" ref={ packRef }>
```

[image]

Assigning the class with Tailwind

```
<div
  className={ classNames('absolute top-full right-0 w-full bg-white mt-2 rounded-lg overflow-hidden shadow-2xl', {
    '!bottom-full': !isVisible
  }) }
  ref={ observe }
>
```

Comment: Your code checks for window intersection, i.e. whether _any part_ of the element is inside the window. If that's not what you want (and it sounds like you don't) don't use that mechansim. Instead, check the element's `getBoundingClientRect` and confirm the bounding box is not fully within the viewport.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans hook sample?

Comment: Why? It's plain JS functionality, just write a function that that works with the HTML element rather than the React vdom node (see Ori Droi's answer), and then call that with `useEffect` yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the element you're trying to observe doesn't exist when the `useEffect` is called, the ref is `null`, and nothing is observed. When the element appears it's not magically observed.

Instead of an object ref, use a callback ref. The callback ref would be called as soon as the element appears. It would initialize the observer if needed, and would observe the element.

You don't need to unobserve a removed item in this case, since the observer maintains weak references to the observed elements.

**Demo** - scroll up and down and toggle the element:

```js
const { useRef, useState, useEffect, useCallback } = React;

const useOnScreen = (rootMargin = '0px') => {
  const observer = useRef();
  const [isIntersecting, setIntersecting] = useState(false);

  // disconnect observer on unmount
  useEffect(() => () => {
    if(observer) observer.disconnect(); // or observer?.disconnect() if ?. is supported
  }, []);

  const observe = useCallback(element => {
    // init observer if one doesn't exist
    if(!observer.current) observer.current = new IntersectionObserver(
      ([entry]) => { setIntersecting(entry.isIntersecting); },
      { rootMargin }
    );

    // observe an element
    if(element) observer.current.observe(element)
  }, [rootMargin]);

  return [isIntersecting, observe];
};


const Demo = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isVisible, observe] = useOnScreen();
  
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="header">
        <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>Toggle {isOpen ? 'on' : 'off'}</button>
        <div>Visible {isVisible ? 'yes' : 'no'}</div>
      </div>
      
      {isOpen && <div className="child" ref={observe} />}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo />);
```

```css
.container {
  height: 300vh;
}

.header {
  top: 10px;
  position: sticky;
}

.child {
  height: 30vh;
  margin-top: 110vh;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

If you want the observer to trigger only when 100% of the element is visible set the [threshold](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#thresholds) to 1 (or any percent the fits your case):

```js
const { useRef, useState, useEffect, useCallback } = React;

const useOnScreen = (rootMargin = '0px') => {
  const observer = useRef();
  const [isIntersecting, setIntersecting] = useState(false);

  // disconnect observer on unmount
  useEffect(() => () => {
    if(observer) observer.disconnect(); // or observer?.disconnect() if ?. is supported
  }, []);

  const observe = useCallback(element => {
    // init observer if one doesn't exist
    if(!observer.current) observer.current = new IntersectionObserver(
      ([entry]) => { setIntersecting(entry.isIntersecting); },
      { 
        rootMargin, 
        threshold: 1 // define the threshold to control what amount of visibility triggers the observer
      }
    );

    // observe an element
    if(element) observer.current.observe(element)
  }, [rootMargin]);

  return [isIntersecting, observe];
};


const Demo = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isVisible, observe] = useOnScreen();
  
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="header">
        <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>Toggle {isOpen ? 'on' : 'off'}</button>
        <div>Fully visible {isVisible ? 'yes' : 'no'}</div>
      </div>
      
      {isOpen && (
        <div 
          className={classNames({ child: true, visible: isVisible })} 
          ref={observe} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo />);
```

```css
.container {
  height: 300vh;
}

.header {
  top: 10px;
  position: sticky;
}

.child {
  height: 30vh;
  margin-top: 110vh;
  background: blue;
}

.visible {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/classnames/2.3.2/index.min.js" integrity="sha512-GqhSAi+WYQlHmNWiE4TQsVa7HVKctQMdgUMA+1RogjxOPdv9Kj59/no5BEvJgpvuMTYw2JRQu/szumfVXdowag==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Note that this will still flag the wrong thing of course, since intersection observer reports "true" if any part of the element is visible inside the viewport, whereas the question was about getting "true" only if the _entire_ element is inside the viewport (hence why getBoundingClientRect is more suited here).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - good point. Missed that part. You can actually use `intersectionObserver` for that as well by setting the threshold. See 2nd part of the answer.

Comment: @OriDrori is there a chance I can now assign class, based on your code? It looks as if Tailwind endlessly re-sets the class definition

Comment: How do you assign the class exactly?

Comment: @Aleksandrs - I've updated the 2nd example with a changing class using the classnames library.

Comment: @OriDrori The issue still exists. Do you mean I have to create an external file?

Comment: Nope. It doesn't seem to be related. Open another question with your exact example.